# php ImageMagick gif resize keep animation

Tags: php, animation, resize, gif

After upload, the gif is resized but the animation is lost. What am I doing wrong?

```
try
{
   $animation = new Imagick($this->image_filename);

   foreach ($animation as $frame)
   {
      $frame->thumbnailImage($width, $height);
      $frame->setImagePage($width, $height, 0, 0);
   }

   $animation->writeImages($this->image_filename, true);

   echo "<img src='".$this->image_filename."' />";

   $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($this->image_filename);
}
catch(Exception $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }
```

No exception caught.

```
Array
(
    [versionNumber] => 1608
    [versionString] => ImageMagick 6.4.8 2011-03-20 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php
The first comment seems like what u need.
And u should never mix GD2 library ("imagecreatefromgif") and Imagick.

Comment: Thank you, you (and the user who wrote the comment) spared me time

Answer (score 2):

I used this function:

```
function gifResize($file_origin,$file_dest,$percent){
   $percent = $percent*100;
   $crop_w = 0;
   $crop_h = 0;
   $crop_x = 0;
   $crop_y = 0;
   $image = new Imagick($file_origin);
   $originalWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
   $originalHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
   $size_w = ($originalWidth*$percent)/100;
   $size_h = ($originalHeight*$percent)/100;
   if(($size_w-$originalWidth)>($size_h-$originalHeight)){
       $s = $size_h/$originalHeight;
       $size_w = round($originalWidth*$s);
       $size_h = round($originalHeight*$s);
   }else{
       $s = $size_w/$originalWidth;
       $size_w = round($originalWidth*$s);
       $size_h = round($originalHeight*$s);
   }
   echo "$originalWidth $size_w - $originalHeight $size_h";
   $image = $image->coalesceImages();

   foreach ($image as $frame) {
       $frame->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y);
       $frame->thumbnailImage($size_h, $size_w);
       $frame->setImagePage($size_h, $size_w, 0, 0);
   }
   $imageContent = $image->getImagesBlob();
   $fp = fopen($file_dest,'w');
   fwrite($fp,$imageContent);
   fclose($fp);
```

}